# Toggle sidebar to partially hid sidebar

Tags: css, sass, frontend, navbar, web-frontend

I'm trying to recreate this side navbar I came across on [zurb.com](http://zurb.com/library). In a nutshell, it's a navbar with an image and text elements. When you click outside the navbar it collapses on itself to conceal the text, leaving just the image still in view.

It's not clear how you can partially hide aspects of a single "li" element. My original guess what that they created classes within a "li" element and hide one of the classes on click, but based on code that doesn't look to be the case.

Any insight would be really helpful. Even the recognized name of a navbar like this would be helpful in pointing me towards a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a clean version of what you posted.

http://codepen.io/OfficialAntarctica/pen/MJxMKd

Basically they have defined an open width - which is not ideal but `width:auto` doesn't work with transitions, the width is on line 23 and will vary for what you choose as items.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

The general idea is that you know the width of the icon/image in the menu, and set the menu's width to that width, then hide the overflow (the text in the menu items). Then when you hover over the menu, transition the width of the menu so that the menu text can be seen.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
nav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 45px;
  transition: width .5s;
  background: #eee;
}
nav:hover, li {
  width: 175px;
}
img {
  width: 45px;
  float: left;
}
li {
  clear: both;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1980294624/DJT_Headshot_V2_400x400.jpg"> blah blah blah</li>
    <li><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/796243884636512260/zHVoWqKV.jpg"> blah blah blah</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If my answer is wrong, I would love someone to explain the downvote(s) so I can learn from my mistakes. This is the same basic technique that OP linked to as far as I understand anyways.